# How do I find a directory or a file in Linux file system

Tags: find, kernel-modules

I am using the find command in my Android image; a image which I developed myself and put in an example of a dynamically loadable module. I put the code in the /example directory of my source code, compiled the code, and flashed the phone with it.

I am not sure if it is relevant to my question, but I put the .ko file in the /proc directory of my ramdisk. I created a /drivers directory and put the ko in there. Now I am trying to find the path to the file so I can activate it, but I do not know if I am using the right command.

I am using find, which I got by installing busybox on my platform. All I want to do is a recursive search from root for the word example. I can not follow why I am getting different results when I issue find. I am posting here since this is essentially a Linux question. My question is how can I find the file(s) / directories I am after please? [Here](http://pastebin.com/5HhuJiiv) is the command I issued and the output I got.

Update after the first comments. Thanks for the help. I have updated the link above with the output. For some reason the ko files don't show up. I do not think they would on the sdcard. I am not sure why I get a permission error, but I don't think that is relevant to my goal any how.

I do know that something is different in this image since I was getting an security error message, which after online research seems to imply that Samsung knox was not happy. It was perhaps the added files. Since I ran this image before successfully for days; actually a version of it without the two files I mentioned. I know that the files are in the image somewhere. As to why I don't see them, it may be a minor Android adjustment. I'll discuss it in xda and see what I get.

Comment: Your pastebin has a lot of output and then a command that searches for "hello". That way you will never find the word "example". What are you trying to do. Please include the appropriate commands in your post, including output (stripped to the relevant minimum). And while you're at it updating your post, please break the wall-of-text into something readable.

Comment: Sorry. Here is more explanation. The folder is /example. In it I put the code for hello1.c. The ko file is hello1.ko. Thanks; I'll update my post in the next few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to avoid "permission denied" errors and search recursively the whole Android filesystem, you'll need to have a "rooted" device.

Afterwards, having a rooted device, you may install any Terminal emulator application, run `su` and run `find` command.

E.g., you'd like to find all files with `.ko` extension, so please run:

`find / -name "*.ko"` in Terminal emulator after running `su` command.